# Building a hierarchy tree for three connected lists inside sharepoint online using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

We have these linked sharepoint lists:-

1. Department list
2. Category List >> has a lookup field to the Department list.
3. Asset list >> has a lookup field to the Category list.

so is there a way using JavaScript + sharepoint rest api to build a tree-like view which will show the related Department >> then under each department to show the related Categories >> and then under each category to show the related Assets?

Thanks

Thank

Answer (score 0):

jsTree plugin offers an easy way to generate a tree view. And it's very convenient to set up its data source:

- https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

[image]

BR